# Custom Routing if Controller action doesn't exist mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

What I want to occur is if the user navigates to a `Controller Action` page like `Home/Index` and action exists then continue as normal. If however the user navigates to a `Controller Action` that does not exist `Home/NotExist` then I want to default it to a "Default" Controller called `MyController`.

I have tried to add a route before the Standard Default route which accepts `*url*`

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "CustomRoute",
                    "{*url}",
                    new { controller = "MyController", action = "MySingleAction" }
     );
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But `Home/Index` is going to the CustomRoute and not the Default

**N.B** I have tried putting the route after and it throws an error

Comment: Have a look at the http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html especially the Handling of 404 Errors. you should be able to route to a default controller/action. this way.

Comment: @Syneryx - Thanks for this, So I have to throw a 404 exception? MVC should try and map the routes before throwing the exception

Comment: As far as i know it will throw a 404 by default when trying to access a wrong URL. and you will automatically be directed to the controller and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should let your custom route be the last route defined. In this case:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "CustomRoute",
                    "{*url}",
                    new { controller = "MyController", action = "MySingleAction" }
     );
```

Comment: The problem is any route with two names /something/else will match the first route with params controller "something" and action "else", even if such a controller/action doesn't exist.  Routes are not smart enough to see if the parameters make sense.  All they are doing is pattern matching.  So the first route may match a custom URL and 404 cause the controller/action doesn't exist.